# understanding basic trick in math problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

i would like  to know what is asked   in the following question:

A shopkeeper marks his goods at $20$% profit and gives discount  of $5$%,i would like to understand  what is main tricky in this problem,gives discount  of $5$%  is it same as  for example original cost was $100$ and after discount became   $95$,  but marks  goods at $20$ percent,it means that after he got  $20$% percent profit,he decrease price by $5$ %?thanks in advance

Comment: Does the 20% profit come after the discount or before the discount?  There is some ambiguity in the statement of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the item costs him 100 and he sells it for 120, then he is making a 20 percent profit. If he takes off 5 percent of the cost, he cuts the item down to 114, and he is now making a 14 percent profit.

Answer (score 2):

Any ambiguity in the order of applying mark-up/discount is irrelevant

If he buys something for 100, the final price is:$$P=100\times 1.20 \times 0.95$$no matter which is multiplied first...